# how to verify style attribute in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-ide

I have the following code:

```
<div class="ui-multiselect-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-multiselect-single" style="width: 192px; top: 172px; left: 299.9px; display: none;">
```

how can i use verifyAttribute or any other command to validate that the style is `display: none;` ?
the xpath that I have is  `/html/body/div[3]`

Answer (score 2):

You have to match your style attribute with xpath contains, for example
`//*[contains(@style,'display: none')]` this means any element which has display: none. you can further refine it like `//div[contains(@style,'display: none')]`

Answer (score 2):

Better late then never...

Command: assertAttribute
Target: css=#div_id@style
Value: *display: none*

Comment: Your answer is not very clear to me. Could you expand/explain further?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the attribute value and verify it.

For example, to check style attribute on span in td:

```
1. Store attribute value in variable:
Command: store atribute
Target: css=tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(3) > span@style
(you can also use xpath here)
Value: estilo

2. Check it with echo (for spaces, colons...):
Command: echo
Target: ${estilo}

3. And verify or assert it:
Command: assert
Target: estilo
Value: color: rgb(111, 235, 10);
```